# What can a high level spellcaster with no spellcasting effectively do?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature

Inspired by [Can Disjunction destroy artifacts in its AoE (maybe accidentally) or only when directly targeting them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72833/can-disjunction-destroy-artifacts-in-its-aoe-maybe-accidentally-or-only-when-d)

One of the effects of [Disjunction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-s-disjunction) is that you can destroy an artifact, but with a risk of losing all spellcasting abilities. While I imagine this isn't a common scenario in most campaigns, I'm curious what place it has in a story. To most players, it feels like losing the central defining mechanic of your character is akin to death, and makes them more or less unplayable. If it's just an NPC, it doesn't take a specific rule for the DM to choose to heavily punish that character for destroying an artifact, and is likely only happening to drive a very specific story.

So really, the biggest impact to a campaign is the effect of that loss on a player character. That being a case, **what, if anything, can a sorcerer or wizard capable of casting 9th level spells do, and still be effective, after losing the ability to cast spells?**

Comment: I've removed the second question which started with *“Additionally, what value does having that rule provide? If it is just to discourage players from mucking up DM's worlds…”* since that's a whole 'nother issue than the rest of the question is asking about. (Normally I'd advise to post a second question in a new question post, but the removed text as-written was a discussion/opinion-based question, so it would probably be summarily closed. If you can think of a way to ask it that allows for concrete answers rather than discussion though, feel free to post it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to note that this condition has very little in common with character death, as character death is a much, much more easily removed condition and not a significant obstacle to progression even if it isn't removed (petitioners can, after all, gain class levels).  That said, this seriousand difficult to remove negative condition need not be the end of your character! Read on, brave adventurer:

*Coping:*
This is pathfinder, not D&D 3.5.  There are *no* classes with spellcasting as their only class feature, and a 20th level Wiz/Sorcerer without the ability to cast spells is still quite a force to be reckoned with.  Some examples:

- A Counterspell Specialist can still Counterspell spells by using the Counterspell Mastery supernatural ability, thus putting their now-useless spell slots to good use.  The are also immune to any one energy type of their choice (including options like 'force', 'sonic', 'city', etc)
- A Divination Specialist still always goes first always no matter what even in surprise rounds of combats they should be unaware of (Technically they just automatically critical their initiative check and also get a +10 bonus and also can act in the surprise round, but this is almost always sufficient to go first, since the minimum initiative total (assuming a -5 from Dex penalty) would be 25 and [Nocticula](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/demon-lords/demon-lord-nocticula), the CR 30 Demon Lord of Assassins, has an average initiative check total of 23).  They also can grant a +10 insight bonus for 1 round to a variety of things, including initiative, a number of times a day.
- An Arcane Sorcerer can spend spell slots to use consumable magic items without consuming them.  This is a big deal.
- Most sorcerer capstones are Su abilities and thus still usable.

**Fixing it:**
You are right that losing spellcasting as a primary spellcasting class can be painful.  However, there is no reason for such a loss to be permanent; the spell only prevents mortal magic from reversing it. Solutions:

- Get a deity to fix it. As extremely high level adventurers you are practically gods yourselves.  Having to go find a somewhat higher-powered being to fix your problems in exchange for currency/quests shouldn't be that new to you.
- Get an artifact to fix it.  Clearly artifacts exist in the campaign commonly enough that you destroyed one.  Presumably it shouldn't be too hard to find a Deck of Many Things and use it to reverse the curse, or any number of other minor artifacts with the ability to do so.

Comment: I like that is answer gives options for continuing that character's story through other useful applications of their skills as well as options to restore the abilities that are well supported by the rules.

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, excepting specific feats or class options, a wizard without spell*casting* still has known spells and has a class level. That means she can activate magic items with the Spell Completion and Spell Trigger activations. Creating items requires you to know spells and have an appropriate caster *level*, not be able to cast certain spells.

So you can make, use, and recharge magic items very, very well. It's not great, but you can make it work.

Comment: This situation oddly enough mirrors the original D&D "war game" concept behind Magic Users/Wizards as being the artillery supporting the Fighting Man.  What you have described makes the "artillery" member of the group a tech/item focused player, which is an ironic reflection of the High Level martial types needing +weapons and +armor to be effective at that level ... so now the whole party is item dependent to a certain extent.  Not sure if this point is worth folding into your reply or not, but I offer it for your consideration in terms of how a player in this situation fits into the party.